# Use glob pattern to include controllers annotations routing with Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, glob, symfony-routing

I want to include all controllers for route annotation, giving a `routes/annotations.yaml`:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/{Site,Dashboard}/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

The `glob` component is not giving folders but `null` (whereas files exist).

How can I use glob pattern in such way?

Comment: try surrounding resource (string) with single quotes: `resource: '../../src/{Site,Dashboard}/Controller/'`

Comment: This is actually a bug, I send a PR right now https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/25633.

Comment: Can't reproduce it now but from the PR seems you are right. Nice catch!